# Is there a melee equivalent for Clustered Shots?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, combat, melee-combat

The [Clustered Shots](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/clustered-shots-combat/) feat says:

> *You take a moment to carefully aim your shots, causing them all to strike nearly the same spot.*
>
> **Prerequisites:** Point-Blank Shot, Precise Shot, base attack bonus +6.
>
> **Benefit:** When you use a full-attack action to make multiple ranged weapon attacks against the same opponent, total the damage from all hits before applying that opponent’s damage reduction.
>
> **Special:** If the massive damage optional rule is being used, that rule applies if the total damage you deal with this feat is equal to or exceeds half the opponent’s full normal hit points (minimum 50 points of damage).

Is there a Paizo feat that does the same thing except for melee attacks instead of ranged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is not

[Clustered Shots](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/clustered-shots-combat/) exists because DR is a bigger problem to ranged attackers, who have fewer means of adding fixed damage to damage rolls than melee attackers, who have a built-in mechanic to increase their damage rolls (strength bonus to damage).

Normally, ranged attackers have the benefit of being able to get more attacks more easily (by not moving in the battlefield), and the way the developers found to counter-balance this was to not allow them to stack the same bonuses to damage available to melee fighters. Or, when possible, making it cost a few more feats.

Fighters have a specific feat to help bypassing damage reduction: [Penetrating Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/penetrating-strike-combat-final/) (and [Greater Penetrating Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-penetrating-strike-combat/)), which will ignore up to 5 points of a typed DR (not DR/-).

For unarmed attackers (like monks), you have the [Pummeling Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-style-combat-style/) feats, which will do exactly that, but that will only work with **unarmed strikes**. This does the same as you ask, but is *very* limited.

Comment: Also [Greater Penetrating Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-penetrating-strike-combat-final/)

Comment: Pummeling Style does not work with natural weapons or Ascetic Style "This ability works only with unarmed strikes, no matter what other abilities you might possess."

Comment: Yeah, reverting my update.

Answer (score -2):

There is a melee equivalent of Clustered Shots, but in a slight different way. It's called "Pummeling Style".

Now first of all, you need to have improved unarmed strikes as feat and either have BAB+6, or Brawlers Flurry, or the monk Flurry to qualify for this style.

> Whenever you use a full-attack action or flurry of blows to make multiple attacks against a single opponent with unarmed strikes, total the damage from all hits before applying damage reduction. **This ability works only with unarmed strikes, no matter what other abilities you might possess**.

It's limited to unarmed strikes, but does basically the exact same thing as clustered shot.

Here is the Link to it. https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-style-combat-style/

Comment: Pummeling Style is specifically called out in both other answers.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Your answer would be well served if you tone down the aggressiveness in your first paragraph. Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Hey @Atalon, I noticed you mentioned that whoever said "there is not" had no idea of the existance of Pummeling Style. I am that guy, and I did mention the feat on my answer. The question is specifically asking for a general way to apply an effect to stack all melee damage before applying DR, which Pummeling strike does, but for a *very* limited number of weapons (unarmed and monk weapons with the proper feat combination). So, if he is a sword-wielding fighter, Pummeling Strike will do nothing for him.

Answer (score -3):

For all intents and purposes, the Vital Strike feats serve a similar purpose to Clustered Shots. Difference is that Clustered Shots allowed the ranged weapon to trigger any additional elemental effects multiple times, as it is multiple attacks, as opposed to Vital Strike which triggers such effects only once.